# Is $x+1$ a factor of $x^{2016}-1$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, polynomials, factoring

$$x^{2016}-1=(x-1)(1+x+x^2+x^3+\dots+x^{2015})$$
If $x+1$ is a factor of $x^{2016}-1$, then $(1+x+x^2+x^3+\dots+x^{2015})=(x+1)G(x)$, where $G(x)$ is some polynomial.

What is $G(x)$ if $x+1$ is also a factor?

Comment: $G(x) = (1+x+\cdots+x^{2015})/(1+x)$.  Is this question "I don't know how to tell if a linear polynomial divides another polynomial" or "I don't know how to do polynomial long division?"

Comment: Is $t-1$ a factor of $t^{1008}-1$? Is $x^2-1$ a factor of $x^{2016}-1$? Is $x+1$ a factor of $x^2-1$? Hence?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hint: If $x_0=-1$ is a zero of $x^{2016}-1$, then $(x-(-1))$ is a factor of $(x^{2016}-1)$.

In order to find $G(x)=(x^{2016}-1)/(x+1)$ you need to apply polynomial long division (you should see the pattern).

Answer (score 5):

Yes, $x+1$ is a factor of $x^{2016}-1$ and
$$x^{2016}-1=(x+1)(x^{2015}-x^{2014}+x^{2013}-\cdots-x^2+x-1)$$
Then
$$G(x)=1+x^2+x^4+\dots+x^{2014}$$
More generally, $x-r$ is a factor of $P(x)$ if and only if $P(r)=0$. In this case, $P(x)=x^{2016}-1$ and $P(-1)=0$, so $x+1$ is a factor of $x^{2016}-1$.

Comment: So x-1 and x+1 cant be both factors of x^2016 - 1 now?  Since its reduced to (x+1) g(x)  now.  x^2016 - 1 is equal to (x+1) g(x) or (x-1) p(x) ,it cant be reduced to (x+1) (x-1) h(x).  So either x-1 or x+1 is the factor, not both.

Comment: @YolandaHui $(x+1)(x-1)(1+x^2+x^4+\dots+x^{2014})=x^{2016}-1$

Comment: Is x^2-1 also a factor?

Comment: @YolandaHui _Yes..._ $(x+1)(x-1)=x^2-1$

Comment: Using geometric series, (x+1)(1+x^2+...+x^2014) is not equal to 1+x+x^2+...+x^2015

Comment: @YolandaHui They are equal. Only even exponents are included in the large term - there's an $x^{144}$ but no $x^{389}$, for example.

Answer (score 3):

Use this simple lemma

> $(x-a)$ is a factor of $P(x)$ if and only if $P(a)=0$

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
x^{2016}-1=&(x^2)^{1008}-1=(x^2-1)((x^2)^{1007}+\dots+x^2+1)\\
&=(x+1)(x-1)(x^{2014}+\dots+x^2+1).
\end{align}